# What is the best way to capitalize every element in an array of strings in Python?

Tags: python

What is the best way to capitalize every element in an array of strings in Python?

This:

```
["a", "able", "about", "across", "after", "all"]
```

Should become that:

```
["A", "Able", "About", "Across", "After", "All"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capitalize:

```
new_list = map(str.capitalize, old_list)
```

Comment: As long as str/unicode aren't being mixed, then `map(str.capitalize, old_list)` is sufficient and avoids the `lambda`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
words = ["a", "able", "about", "across", "after", "all"]
cap_words = [word.title() for word in words]
```

Comment: For just single words... it's probably more efficient to use `str.capitalize` as `str.title` will capitalize each word (so has a split/join op overhead)

Comment: @JonClements: Had forgotten about [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)